# How do I make Canvas and non-Canvas objects stick to each other?

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas

I've got a board with checkers. The squares and the pieces are separate objects with a SpriteRenderer component.

I want to create an information window to the right of the board, containing additional information just like on Lichess:

[image]

The problem is the info window is a Canvas object. However, in being so, when the screen aspect ratio gets changed, the window behaves weirdly, moving aside:

[image]
[image]

What is a good way to glue the info window to the board?

Comment: why not rather go fully Canvas then? Instead of `SpriteRenderer` use `Image`

Comment: @derHugo The thing is in this case I can't move my checkers properly. A checker is a child of a square in the hierarchy. That is this way so that I could place a checker in the center of a square simply settting its localPosition to zero. So, if I make it via Canvas, when a checker is moved it sometimes gets underneath a square and it can't be fully seen. I mean it is higher, than neighbour squares in the hierarchy, therefore lower on the screen.

Comment: That’s what sorting order is for. If the pieces have the right order. Then they will always show in the right place.

Comment: @BugFinder Sorting order is a property of SpriteRenderer, not Image, isn't it? [SortingOrder](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-sortingOrder.html)

Comment: Image uses depth for some reason but it works out the same thing pushing it back and forth in the drawing order

Comment: well instead of changing the parent and setting `transform.localPosition = 0;` rather simply keep it at the bottom (=> rendered on top of the board) and use `transform.position = tile.position;` ?

Comment: @derHugo Yeah, I thought up your suggestion once more yesterday and I came to a similar decision. I now keep 2 canvases: for the board and for the rest (in order not to mix them). And the checkers are always lower than the squares in the hierarchy. That must've been an easy sollution and I already feel foolish for this question:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Take `var point = SpriteRenderer.bounds.max` of the board (rop-right point)
2. Then use that point in `var position = Camera.Main.WorldToScreenPoint(point)` method to translate that position to the canvas
3. Set position to the panel you want to glue to the board
   hint: to decide what part to glue to that point use `RectTransofrm.pivot`
   [example in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Jbxi.png)